# IE 6/7 - Header disappears?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, header, hidden

In IE 6/7 (i don't know/care about 6) my header don't show up for some reason. The strange thing is it does take up space, it's just not visible for some reason. My first thought was it's just collapsing, but that can't be the case since it takes up space. I tried making it visible with `visibility: visible;`, `display:block;` and `opacity:1;` but no difference. I didn't excpect it to work either, since i haven't hidden the element in any way, but it was worth trying. Now i'm out of ideas and i don't know what causes this.

I'm testing with IETester on Windows 8.

Site url: http://goo.gl/Q8J6v

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IE 6/7 doesn't know the "header" html element. You should use html5shiv (m), to enable styling html5 elements

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: Ah i should have mentioned that, i already included a fix for it. You just need to create the element with javascript for it to work properly; `document.createElement('header');`. Either way, i use a <header> tag in the content as well and it displays properly down there, so that's not the issue.

Comment: I just tried html5shiv, no difference. I just noticed the footer is also gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a script that clones the background image url (from the css) and creates a new `<img>` tag that stretches it across the screen (fallback for background-size). Since it has to be behind the content it's displayed relative with a z-index of 0. The problem was i had forgotten to bump up the z-index for header and footer to 1, that's why it wasn't visible (the background was above it).